# Generate 2-4 char alpha-numeric

Tags: c#, string

I need a function that return a `List<string>` in c#.

The function need to return **all possibilities** for :

2-4 characters alphanumeric (a-z A-Z 0-9)

Have you got any purpose to make a fast generation function? (Fast generation needed)

Comment: You want to create a `List<string>` with all those possibilities? Have you worked out just how many such strings there are, and how much memory they would take?

Comment: Do you mean it must return a List object? because I doubt any computer could handle a list that big...

Comment: You might need a few zettabytes of memory, but it's doable. Got a TARDIS handy? Maybe they'll have that sort of computer eventually.

Comment: @TimS. - you actually can derive from `List<string>` so you can return permutation on demand instead of actually storing in the list... but yes - what purpose such list would serve is unclear.

Comment: sum((26+26+10)!/((26+26+10)-n)!,n,2,10) = 361,674.351 terabytes... lol no (just in case you didn't understand Tim S's joke)

Comment: I haven't got a super computer, but i need to decrypt a file, and i need to test key's in 2-10 characters alphanumeric (a-z A-Z 0-9).

Comment: haha I knew! it was for a password cracker, also my math is wrong, that's the number of strings, each string will be more than 1 byte, and lets add an extra 16 bytes for C#'s overhead in the list and string containers: sum(n*((26+26+10)! / ((26+26+10)-n)!)+16,n,2,10) = 3,609,793.27 terabytes

Comment: My point is, stop at about 6 characters, you should be trying to break the encryption analytically at this point.

Comment: @Michael - then just make a string, test it, then discard it if it failed. There's no reason (and as Jon Skeet and MickLH pointed out, no memory) to store the entire list.

Comment: ok, have you got a function purpose to test it with a fully optimised implementation?

Comment: Optimized solution? Find the guy who encrypted the file and ask him what the password is.

Comment: It is for a XOR decryption, i need to find the key :)

Comment: Obligatory: http://www.xkcd.com/538/ (the lesson, also applicable here, being that typical encryption is so strong that head-on, brute force attacks are impossible; other sorts of attacks, however, might be possible)

Comment: @Michael scanning key this way is in fact still used somewhere but they have *supercomputers*, I don't think you can follow this technology.

Comment: Can anyone can purpose me the best way to find that key for decryption, what is the best solution 2-3 alpha numeric char max? maybe 4?5?6?

Comment: @Michael - this sounds vaguely like the crypto-challenges I did for Matasano. I've got an implementation on my box somewhere, but the whole point was to get practice implementing different crypto solutions, so I can't share it.

Comment: Ok, by the way i'm just searching a fully optimized function to generate all possibilities for 2-3 char alpha numeric :')

Comment: You might update your post title then, since it still says 2-10 characters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to have this as a list, you definitely won't fit it into any existing memory. It's roughly (58^10+58^9+58^8... bytes).

However, you could try something like this:

```
// this generates all strings for characters 0-3 with lengths 2-3
List<string> result = GenerateStrings("0123", 2, 3);

private List<string> GenerateStrings(string allowedChars, int fromLength, int toLength)
{
    List<string> strings = new List<string>();

    int charsNum = allowedChars.Length;

    for (int currentLength = fromLength; currentLength <= toLength; currentLength++)
    {
        // initialize array of indexes to generate individual characters
        int[] indexes = new int[currentLength];
        do
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(currentLength);
            // generate characters based on current index values
            for (int charPosition = 0; charPosition < currentLength; charPosition++)
            {
                sb.Append(allowedChars[indexes[charPosition]]);
            }
            strings.Add(sb.ToString());
            // until we can increment indexes array (still some character combinations available)
        } while (IncrementIndex(indexes, charsNum - 1, currentLength - 1));
    }

    return strings;
}

/// <summary>
/// Have array of integer indexes such as [0,0,0] with valid values 0-9. 
/// This function increments indexes from right by one with correct overflow handling, 
/// such that value [0,0,3] is incremented to [0,0,4], value [0,2,9] to [0,3,0] etc.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if increment was successful, false if maximal value was reached.</returns>
private bool IncrementIndex(int[] indexes, int maxItemValue, int incrementFromPosition)
{
    indexes[incrementFromPosition]++;
    // check if current position overflow allowed range
    if (indexes[incrementFromPosition] > maxItemValue)
    {
        if (incrementFromPosition == 0)
        {
            // we reached left-most position and can't increment more
            return false;
        }

        indexes[incrementFromPosition] = 0;
        // increment next position to the left
        return IncrementIndex(indexes, maxItemValue, incrementFromPosition-1);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

List lst = new List() { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" };

```
        List<string> newlst = (from p in lst
                               from q in lst
                               select p + q).ToList();
```

Comment: Does Linq is optimised for this kind of function?

Comment: This returns only combinations of size 2, not 3 or 4.

Comment: for size N use (from p1 in lst
                                   from q2 in lst
                                   .
                                   .
                                   .
                                   from pN in lst

                                   select p1 + p2 + ... +PN).ToList()